# HttpUrlConnection doesn't send a request until getResponseCode is called

Tags: android, get, httpurlconnection

To put data into a database I use a GET-request. I tried to send one from within Android to my server, but the data I sent, did not appear in the database. Then I just added `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();` and everything got working fine.

So, the following is not working until the last string is uncommented

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpURLConnection.connect();
    //httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
}
```

My question: Why does the request get sent only if I call `getResponseCode`?

Comment: have you taken internet permission in manifests ?

Comment: @kdblue for sure. I did it a long before.

Comment: What is the problem in adding `.getResponseCode()` ? and keep it working

Comment: @Barns My question: Why do the request gets sent only if I call ``getResponseCode``?

Comment: @NileshDeokar the only problem is I don't understand why I should call this method if I'm not interested in its result. And there is no information at developer.android.com that if i want to reach a site I must call ``getResponseCode``. Hope you understand what I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: Directly from Java Docs --> "You are not always required to explicitly call the connect method to initiate the connection. Operations that depend on being connected, like getInputStream, getOutputStream, etc, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.

Now that you've successfully connected to your URL, you can use the URLConnection object to perform actions such as reading from or writing to the connection. The next section shows you how." -- So basically you are only establishing a connection. You then need to do something with it, this `getResponseCode` triggers this

Comment: @Barns thank you. This can be the answer to the question. I just thought that it's enough to call ``url.openConnection()`` and after that ``httpURLConnection.connect()``

Comment: Take a look at the Java Docs :: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html  :: You will see by this example that you don't even need to call `connect()` as it is implicitly called be certain read and write methods.